# Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics/loggers in Azure API Manager ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

This is how the chunk of the ARM template looks:

```json
{
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics/loggers",
    "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
    "name": "[concat(variables('gatewayName'), '/applicationinsights/', variables('gatewayName'))]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics', variables('gatewayName'), 'applicationinsights')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('gatewayName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "loggerType": "applicationInsights",
        "credentials": {
            "instrumentationKey": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsights')), '2014-04-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        },
        "isBuffered": true,
        "resourceId": "[variables('appInsights')]"
    }
},
```

For two days our ARM template deployment is failing with the error:
`{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"MethodNotAllowedInPricingTier\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Method not allowed in this pricing tier\",\r\n    \"details\": null\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}`

Although the error states the pricing tier, there were no changes in the template.
Verbatim google search [result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Microsoft.ApiManagement%2Fservice%2Fdiagnostics%2Floggers%22&oq=%22Microsoft.ApiManagement%2Fservice%2Fdiagnostics%2Floggers%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0i30j0i8i30.1301j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows that the resource existed before as the first result [item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/diagnostics/loggers).
The documentation does not mention it anymore in the [`diagnostics`](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2018-01-01/service/diagnostics?tabs=bicep) section.

GitHub, though, [remembers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/26b9266b19373f37faf25a9a07dfc42418ee94fa/schemas/2018-01-01/Microsoft.ApiManagement.json#L1130) the resource but mentions different properties within the object:

```json
"service_diagnostics_loggers": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "apiVersion": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "2018-01-01"
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "(^[\\w]+$)|(^[\\w][\\w\\-]+[\\w]$)",
              "maxLength": 80
            },
            {
              "$ref": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/common/definitions.json#/definitions/expression"
            }
          ],
          "description": "Logger identifier. Must be unique in the API Management service instance."
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics/loggers"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "apiVersion",
        "name",
        "type"
      ],
      "description": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics/loggers"
    }
```

It looks like the resource was removed from the ARM template infrastructure silently. What is wrong my analysis?

Comment: The solution we used was to remove the resource that generated the error. You suggested the migration to a new version, but for me one all-of-a-sudden-failing resource is not a good argument for migration. I expect some clear explanation of what exactly happened and why the resource started to generate errors on deployment.

Answer (score 2):

diagnostics/loggers resource does exist in 2018-01-01 API version: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/apimanagement/resource-manager/Microsoft.ApiManagement/stable/2018-01-01/apimdiagnostics.json

After that though it was removed and replaced by loggerId property on diagnostic entity itself: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/apimanagement/resource-manager/Microsoft.ApiManagement/stable/2019-01-01/definitions.json#L1771

We'll check why older API version doesn't seem to work, meanwhile you could try migrating to a newer API version.